# Ionic color text depending on condition

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a very makeshift solution to highlight text in a small slider after user tap.

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let loopValue of values">
<div *ngIf="viewValue == loopValue">
    <b>
        {{loopValue}}
    </b>
</div>
<div *ngIf="viewValue != loopValue">
    {{loopValue}}
</div>
</ion-slide>
```

Here, I highlight the selection by wrapping the slide content into a **bold** bracket. However, I rather would like the font to be ionic defined **primary** or **secondary** color to highlight user tap. How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ionic 4**
You can use the color property of the [ion-text](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/text/) tag. Then your code could look somehow like this:

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let loopValue of values">
  <ion-text [color]="viewValue == loopValue ? 'primary' : 'light'">
   {{loopValue}}
  </ion-text>
</ion-slide>
```

**Ionic 3**
Because there is no `ion-text` tag you should use `ion-item` instead.
Here is an example (also created one on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-3-slides-color)):

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let loopValue of values">
    <ion-item [color]="viewValue == loopValue ? 'primary' : 'light'">
      {{loopValue}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

In this way, you do not have to replicate the whole tag with a `*ngIf`. Instead, the color of the `ion-text` depends on the ternary operator inside the `color`-property.

Comment: Thanks. Did you mean to replace `div` with `ion-text`? Because the above code fails.

Comment: `ion-text` is not a known element

Comment: Oh sorry. Seems like that tag just been added in ionic 4. Do you have an answers otherwise I will investigate later this day.

Comment: If you know for ionic 3 that would be great! :)

Comment: I already changed my answer above. Think the second part should fit your needs! @ElDude

Comment: The `ion-item` kind of works . It changes the background color of the item, not the font color. Any idea? Also, how do I switch back to the default color? What is the ionic default color name? The color of an object without any modifier. Can you add this keyword to the code above?

Comment: The color name is 'light'. NM & thanks for the code above.